# How to configure failover in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Is there a way in sqlalchemy for the developer to specify multiple mysql hosts to try to connect to, and if the 1st one fails to connect it will automatically failover to the 2nd?

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Comment: No, I ended up using mysql-proxy to solve it

Comment: Check out https://haalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ from the author of SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution on mysql used the driver named *MySQL Connector/Python* who's **connect()** function can accept an argument named **failover**.

Hope it will help some people in future.

Here is the reference links:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqlconnector

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

And here, my test code

```
global engine, session, metadata
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
import mysql.connector
import time

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='mysql+mysqlconnector://test:test2013@172.16.1.160:24801/test?charset=utf8'
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE=45
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_MAX_OVERFLOW=45

connect_args={
    'raise_on_warnings': True,
    'failover': [{
        'user': 'test',
        'password': 'test2013',
        'host': '172.16.1.160',
        'port': 24802,
        'database': 'test',
    }, {
        'user': 'test',
        'password': 'test2013',
        'host': '172.16.1.160',
        'port': 24803,
        'database': 'test',
    }]
}
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,connect_args=connect_args,
                       pool_size=SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE,
                       max_overflow=SQLALCHEMY_POOL_MAX_OVERFLOW)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                      autoflush=False,
                                      bind=engine))
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)


base= 2000

while True:
    base+=1
    info = "info%s"%base
    print info
    results = session.execute("insert into t1 values(%s,'%s')"%(base,info))
    print results
    session.commit()
    time.sleep(10)
```