# How to handle MySQL failover within celery

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, celery

I'm trying to implement a failover strategy when my MySQL backend is down in Celery.

I found in [this other stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266171/how-to-configure-failover-in-sqlalchemy) that failover is made possible in SQLAlchemy. However, I couldn't write the same behavior in Celery using `sqlalchmey_engine_options`

```
__app.conf.result_backend = 'db+mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo'
__app.conf.sqlalchmey_engine_options = {
    'connect_args': {
        'failover': [{
            'user': 'root',
            'password': 'password',
            'host': 'http://other_db.com',
            'database': 'dbname'
        }]
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is if the first backend `scott:tiger` does not respond, then it switches to `root:password` backend.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely more than one way to achieve failover. You could start with simple try..except and handle situation when your prefered backend is not responding, in simplest (and probably not very pythonic) way you could try something like this:

```
try:
    # initialise your SQL here and also set the connection up
except:
    # initialise your backup SQL here
```

You could also move your backend selection to the infrastructure so it's transparent from your application perspective, i.e. by using session pooling system (I am not MySQL user but in PostgreSQL world we have **pgpool**).

--- edit ---

I realised you probably want to have your database session and connection handled by celery itself. So very likely above does not answer your question directly, in my simple project I initialise database connection within tasks that require it as in my particular case most tasks do not require database at all.

Comment: Indeed, it's a celery question, I'd like to connect my cluster of MySQL server with celery through SQLAlchemy

Comment: If I understand correctly you would like to have your celery worker process to maintain database session for you so you have one session per worker for a life time of the worker. You could initialise your database manually within your task (i.e. start connection/session and then dispose it manually) but I gather this is not what you want to do.